# How do I find count of values in redis in javascript?

Tags: javascript, redis, node-redis

@assignedPerson:{John | Jane | Alice}
this is my query. I want to find how many values are there in redis. Much like countDocuments() in mongoose.
Is there any way I can achieve that?

Couldn't find much example online. Please help me out

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.